# Whoops, looks like something went wrong. on server

Tags: laravel, deployment, server

I uploaded all laravel project on server, its working fine on local but getting error on server, even database configuration and key  is configured in env. file. even i renamed .env.example file as .env too but got same error.

Error is

> "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

my error log is here:

> [2017-11-06 15:19:07] local.ERROR: exception 'RuntimeException' with
>   message 'The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC
>   with the correct key lengths.' in
>   /home/rndspot5/public_html/dev/lea/vendor/laravel/framework/‌​src/Illuminate/Encry‌​ption/Encrypter.php:‌​43

Comment: You definitely must fix something that went wrong.

Comment: We need more information to give any help, this is just too vague. Turn on your debug (APP_DEBUG=true in your .env file) and give us the information

Comment: Check `laravel.log` file to know more about the error.

Comment: There's a number of things that could go wrong when uploading it to your server. Have you ran `composer install`?

Comment: my error log is here [2017-11-06 15:19:07] local.ERROR: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.' in /home/rndspot5/public_html/dev/lea/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php:43

Comment: run `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: how is it possible my files are uploaded on server and i will generate key? i generated on local cmd and copy key and paisted in .env

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your error, you need to run `php artisan key:generate` this will update your key of which in turn will rectify your error.

You will need to either SSH into your public_html folder if you have host permission to do so. Alternatively, you can ask your host provider to either:

1. Grant you SSH access
2. Perform this action for you.

You can then run: `php artisan config:clear` once the new key has been generated.

Comment: You will need to go in via ssh, does your host allow you to perform this action?

Comment: yes i am here and this is really new thing for me, here is a form to fill, three things here, new key, upload key, and manage current key. will you help me more.

Comment: Are you signed in via SSH (terminal / putty)?

Comment: no idea, how to connect with ssh, but trying, getting error "connection timeout" again and agian

Comment: I'd suggest speaking with your host provider in this instance and see if they'd grant you ssh access or even see if they support Laravel (as you need command line access)

Answer (score 1):

If you are on shared hosting you can use these steps

1. Open your **.env** file, copy `APP_KEY` to somewhere else as a backup
2. Run `php artisan key:generate` from console
3. Copy the new `APP_KEY` and upload it to the **.env** file on your (shared) server
4. Move the old key back to development

Comment: can i use key that i generated on localhost?

Comment: I would advise against using the same key for development and production, but you can indeed do that. But why not generate a second key?

Comment: because i have no experience of ssh and putty. but i am trying, getting error "connection timeout" again and agian

Comment: You can upload the files at the moment right? So you can re-upload the .env file.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue, by adding web app url in .env and Config/App.php and now its working :) thanks all of you for sharing such a value able knowledge that will help me, may be later.